# Php upgrade from 5.3 to php 5.6 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I am following this tutorial on upgrading php from ver 5.3 to 5.6 :http://phpave.com/upgrade-php-53-to-php-56-on-ubuntu-1204-lts/

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

The problem is that apache is also upgraded. Is it possible to update only php without upgrading apache server ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sudo LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5.6
```

Comment: It is saying E: Unable to locate package php5.6
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php5.6'

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `apt-get upgrade` instead of `apt-get dist-upgrade`

Answer (score -1):

Use this command:

```
sudo apt-get install php5
```

Answer (score -2):

Safest way to do it is to do an entire OS update to ubuntu 14LTS. From there you can update using the following PPA:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install php5
```