# How to install PHP 5.6+ on Ubuntu 12.04 using tasksel?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, php-5.6

I recently downgraded one of my laptop from 14.04 to 12.04. Reason for downgrading operating system is speed only. 12.04 seems 10x time faster then my experience with 14.04 on my low configuration laptop. As usual I install LAMP stack using `tasksel` command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install tasksel
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

However, this installed PHP version 5.3.10. I google to update php version and followed many suggestions including `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and also installing latest PPA as well.

Also fllowed this answer: [Php upgrade from 5.3 to php 5.6 on Ubuntu 12.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30776257/php-upgrade-from-5-3-to-php-5-6-on-ubuntu-12-04)

Nothing worked so far and I am here for seeking some help.

Comment: try that it work for me https://askubuntu.com/questions/761713/how-can-i-downgrade-from-php-7-to-php-5-6-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 has reached end of life, so it shouldn't be used in normal cases. If 14.04 is slower for you, you may want to consider a different distribution (like Debian), or a different desktop (i.e. not Unity).

Comment: @NickCoons I have tried both Unity and Gnome and both desktops seems slow to me with 14.04. Finally, I decided to try 12.04 again. I strongly believe there must be a work around of this. Like updating task list or other things. The final solutions will be to install everything separately.

Comment: @عارفبنالأزرق I tried it. Added PPA `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php` however while installing it says there is not php5.6 package available.

Comment: You could try Xfce or Mate, both are quite a bit zippier than Gnome or Unity.

Comment: Let me check Xface & Mate

Comment: @NickCoons later I used Xfce + Openbox